# If variable equal to 0

Tags: c++

Then it will reset to the questions number 1.

I wanted to implement health points system in my code, so that if your hp goes to 0 (zero) when choosing the wrong answer, it will start to question number 1

I'm new to c++ and doesn't know much about it but if you have any recommendation how to improve my coding i'm happy to take your advice.

**Code:**

```
void questions()
{   
    int score, end, hp = 1;
    char ans[28];

     cout <<"\t\tHEALTH POINTS= " << hp <<"\n\n";
     cout << "1.What thing has to be broken before it can be used?\n\n";    //Questions
     cout << "[A]-Egg,";
     cout << " [B]-Heart,";     //Choices
     cout << " [C]-Cube,";
     cout << " [D]-Case";
     cout << "\n\n";
     cout << "YOUR ANSWER IS: ";
     cin  >> ans[1];

      if (ans[1]=='a'||ans[1]=='A')     //This will decide if the input is correct
          {
          cout << "YOUR ANSWER IS CORRECT: [A] - Egg \n\n";
          score++;
          }
      else
          {
            cout <<"\nWRONG! ";
            cout <<"YOU NOW HAVE "<< (hp=(hp-1)) <<" HP LEFT\n\n";
          }

     cout << "2.Jimmy's mother had three children. The first was called April, \nthe second was called May. What was the name of the third?\n";
     cout << "[A]-May,";
     cout << " [B]-Jimmy,";
     cout << " [C]-April,";
     cout << " [D]-Third";  
     cout << "\n\n";
     cout << "Your Answer is: ";
     cin  >> ans[2];

      if (ans[2]=='b'||ans[2]=='B')
          {
          cout << "YOUR ANSWER IS CORRECT: [B] - Jimmy \n\n";
          score++;
          }
      else
          {
            cout <<"\nWRONG! ";
            cout <<"YOU NOW HAVE "<< (hp=(hp-1)) <<" HP LEFT\n\n";
          }

cout << "\n\t\t   YOUR SCORE IS:" << score << "/2, ";
cout <<"YOU HAVE "<< hp <<" HP LEFT\n\n";
cout << endl;
cout <<"\n\t\t     PRESS ANY KEY TO GO BACK TO CHOICES...";
getch(); //Holds the screen
system("cls");
questions();
```

Comment: Something is missing from your stackoverflow.com question about C++. That would be an actual question about C++. The above describes what you want to do. Well, ok? What is your question?

Comment: "_if you have any recommendation how to improve my coding i'm happy to take your advice_" - That sounds like something for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you aware that index of arrays, vectors, strings, starts always with 0 in C++? `ans[1]` (which stores answer of first question) is the _2nd_ element of `char ans[28];`, `ans[0]` - the first, (and consequently `ans[27]` the last). It's not necessarily an issue but it's something (else) which catched my eye. So, I found it worth to be mentioned...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve your approach might be implementing some sort of function to handle asking a question, with predefined choices, and getting an answer back. Instead of writing the code out twice like you do above to ask two questions, you could call the same function twice, passing in the different arguments.